# mysql join 2 tables, 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql

let's say I have

table `student_data` and fields are

```
╔════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║ ID ║ CREATED_BY ║ UPDATED_BY ║
╠════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║  1 ║          1 ║          2 ║
╚════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

table `creator_updater` and fields are

```
╔════╦════════════════╗
║ ID ║      NAME      ║
╠════╬════════════════╣
║  1 ║ The Creator    ║
║  2 ║ Second Creator ║
╚════╩════════════════╝
```

so I wonder what is the exact code so it will show

```
student_data

╔════╦═══════════════╦══════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ CREATED_BY_ID ║ LATEST_UPDATED_BY_ID ║
╠════╬═══════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ The Creator   ║ Second Creator       ║
╚════╩═══════════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

i tried join syntax, but it seems different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to join the `creator_updater` table twice so you can get the names of the two columns.

```
SELECT  a.id,
        b.name created_by_id,
        c.name latest_updated_by_id
FROM    student_data a
        INNER JOIN creator_updater b
            ON a.created_by = b.id
        INNER JOIN creator_updater c
            ON a.updated_by = c.id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c28e/1)

but the code above will not work if one of the columns is *nullable*, if that's the case, use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.id,
        b.name created_by_id,
        c.name latest_updated_by_id
FROM    student_data a
        LEFT JOIN creator_updater b
            ON a.created_by = b.id
        LEFT JOIN creator_updater c
            ON a.updated_by = c.id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4f760/2)

For more information about joins

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: yeah, that what I'm talking about. thanks bro, I'll ask again if I got questions