# How to join two tables, using specific columns multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, view

I have the following 2 tables:

**A) Tables**

**Following**

```
    id
    fkUserName
    follow_fkUserName
```

**UserProfile**

```
    id
    fkUserName
    Name
    Surname
```

**B) What I am trying to do**

I would like to join these two tables as per below:

```
    id
    User_fkUserName
    User_Name
    User_Surname
    Followed_fkUserName
    Followed_Name
    Followed_Surname
```

**C) My Problem:**

My problem is that when I try to join through a view, I am not getting the expected result.

I would like that finally I will have this result:

```
Id  User_fkUsername  User_Name User_Surname Followed_fkUserName Followed_Name      Followed_Surname
1   pbean            Paul      Bean         mWhite              Mary               White
```

**D) Code I am Using:**

The below is the code that I am using for the Join:

```
    CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwFollowingUsers]
    AS SELECT   
    a.Id,
    b.Name User_Name, 
    c.Surname User_Surname, 
    d.Name Followed_Name,
    e.Surname Followed_Surname

    FROM Following a

    LEFT JOIN UserProfile b ON a.fkUserName = b.fkUserName
    LEFT JOIN UserProfile c ON a.fkUserName = c.fkUserName
    LEFT JOIN UserProfile d ON a.follow_fkUserName = d.fkUserName
    LEFT JOIN UserProfile e ON a.follow_fkUserName = e.fkUserName
```

**E) This is what I am getting:**

**vwFollowingUsers**

```
Id      User_Name       Followed_Name
1       Paul            Mary
```

I was following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788515/mysql-join-2-tables-2-columns/13788546#13788546)

**F) Updated Code**

After I posted my question here I have updated my code as per below:

```
    CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwFollowingUsers]
    AS SELECT
    A.Id,
    B.fkUserName AS User_fkUserName,
    B.Name AS User_Name,
    B.Surname AS User_Surname,
    C.fkUserName AS Followed_fkUsername,
    C.Name AS Followed_Name,
    C.Surname AS Followed_Surname

    FROM Following A
    INNER JOIN UserProfile B ON A.fkUserName = B.fkUserName
    INNER JOIN UserProfile C ON A.follow_fkUserName = C.fkUserName;
```

**G) Actual Data:**

This is the actual data (as requested)

**Following**

```
    Id fkUsername       follow_fkUserName
    2  nic@gmail.com    steph@gmail.com
```

**UserProfile**

```
 

    Id  UserPhoto            Description    fkUserName      Name      Surname
    1   ../Files/nich.jpg    test           nich@gmail.com  Nich      White
    2   ../Files/nich2.jpg   null           nich2@gmail.com Nich2     White2
    3   ../Files/steph.jpg   null           steph@gmail.com Stephania Borg
```

I am using Visual Studio and I am trying to create a view which will give me the results as mention in section G of my question.

Comment: Why do you have 4 joins, when you can do it with two?

Comment: I was trying to do it with two... but I didnt manage :/

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output. And please clearify the RDBMS (product and version). At the moment this is tagged with `mysql` and with `sql-server`

Comment: @Shnugo I have provided sample data and expected output. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join **UserProfile** only 2 times 1 for fetching data for user and another for follower.

Try this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwFollowingUsers]

    AS SELECT A.id, 
              B.fkUserName AS User_fkUserName, 
              B.Name AS User_Name, 
              B.Surname AS User_Surname, 
              C.fkUserName AS Followed_fkUserName, 
              C.Name AS Followed_Name,
              C.Surname AS Followed_Surname,
         FROM Following A 
         LEFT JOIN UserProfile B ON A.fkUserName = B.fkUserName 
         LEFT JOIN UserProfile C ON A.follow_fkUserName = C.fkUserName;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply... However  only the following columns are showing up: id, User_Name,  Followed_Name

Comment: @Nichs Can you put your data and structure in sql fiddle and share that link. so we can directly check over there

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 4 joins here - you only want to extract **two** rows from `UserProfile`.
You can simply do the following:

```
SELECT   f.Id,
         up1.fkUserName User_fkUsername,
         up1.Name User_Name, 
         up1.Surname User_Surname, 
         up2.fkUserName Followed_fkUsername,
         up2.Name Followed_Name,
         up2.Surname Followed_Surname
FROM Following f
INNER JOIN UserProfile up1 ON f.fkUserName = up1.fkUserName
INNER JOIN UserProfile up2 ON f.fkUserName = up2.fkUserName
```